# Lenovo Legion 5 Pro 16ACH6H brightness control problem with Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: lenovo, screen, brightness

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsvYt.png)

I just got a new installation of Ubuntu 22.04. The screen brightness control not working. The configuration of the machine and linux distro in the image.

*** I followed these steps:

```
sudo vim /etc/default/grub

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nvidia-drm.modeset=1 acpi_backlight=native nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1"

sudo update-grub
```

But it's not working. I installed brightness-controller, and it worked the first day and now it's not working too. The screen refresh rate is frozen at 93.00Hz.

For this high brightness, I can't use my machine. I would highly appreciate any help to fix this problem. Thanks.

Here is the output of this command

```
lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'

01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo GA104M [GeForce RTX 3070 Mobile / Max-Q]
    Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GA104 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
```

Comment: What is the point of adding `nvidia` options if you don't have an Nvidia device?

Comment: this machine has a graphics card "nvidia rtx 3070"

Comment: Did you install Nvidia drivers? Remove all those options from grub and install drivers.

Comment: In settings I see "llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.6, 256 bits)" is detected in Graphics instead of the rtx 3070 nividia. Would you please help me on the way how to install drivers. I am a new user in Liinux.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 question edited and the output added.

Comment: Install drivers by `ubuntu-drivers install` and remove all that  `"nvidia-drm.modeset=1 acpi_backlight=native nvidia.NVreg_RegistryDwords=EnableBrightnessControl=1"`

Comment: Get this output on command "ubuntu-drivers install"

.......
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/UbuntuDrivers/detect.py", line 839, in nvidia_desktop_pre_installation_hook
    with_nvidia_kms = version >= 470
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'version' referenced before assignment

Comment: Did you do something with python?

Comment: I got the python installed on this machine. Then I installed some other python extensions.

Comment: Should I remove Python first?

Comment: You installed a wrong version of python and broke everything.

Comment: I got the python installed with Ubuntu 22.04 from the PC store. I didn't installed it myself. However, what should I do now? Would you please help?

Comment: I don't know what you did with python. If you re-install the system and install Nvidia drivers, most likely it will be fixed.

Comment: I don't know how to re-install the system!

Comment: The same way you installed it before.

Comment: The service team from the computer store (I bought the laptop from) has installed the ubuntu system. As for the last 8 years, I used to use Windows. This is the first time I am using Linux.

Comment: You can easily find how to install Ubuntu. You can do it again. Maybe they did something wrong.

Comment: I think so! I will try it myself. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

So I faced the same problem when I selected the nvidia-driver-525-open in `Software & Updates > Additional Drivers`

Then I switched to nvidia-driver-525 and the problem seems to have disappeared. I didn't change any other system settings.

[image]